# Spotify API Error 403 User not approved for app: when trying to access user information of other user other than the app owner

Tags: javascript, axios, spotify

I have a simple react app that have a login page and after login will show you the details of the user that logged in.

I was following the Authentication Code flow from their authentication guide. I was able to get the code, exchange it for token and refresh token. I was also able to access my own information from https://api.spotify.com/v1/me. But after trying with my other spotify account, I am getting an Error 403 User not approved for app. I was also able to get the token here but requesting info from https://api.spotify.com/v1/me is getting error.

Comment: From the Spotify developer forum: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Some-API-endpoints-randomly-return-error-403/m-p/5238616/highlight/true#M2983

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue yesterday. There has been a recent update to Spotify for Developers ([Improving the developer and user experience for third-party apps](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2021/05/27/improving-the-developer-and-user-experience-for-third-party-apps/) May 27th, 2021). You have to specifically add users to your app in the Spotify for Developers dashboard now (see the link for more info).